# How do I convert this simple piece of jQuery to coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I've tried all sorts of things, none of which work

I need the following in coffeescript

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: '+=' + $('#comment-div').offset().top + 'px'
}, 'fast');
```

Thanks

Comment: That should work as is in Coffeescript as well.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what you have tried and how they didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As Thilo said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12830525/x#comment17357916_12830525), your JavaScript code as-is works in CoffeeScript, too, but if you want to make it more CoffeeScript-y, you can. Since the languages are so similar, there is not much difference.

```
$("html, body").animate {
    scrollTop: "+=#{$("#comment-div").offset().top}px"
}, "fast"
```

What I've done here is:

- Removed the unnecessary parentheses.
- Use string interpolation (`#{}` syntax) within the `scrollTop` string.

These make the code more CoffeeScript-y.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the fastest way to convert, then try this as a temporary solution

```
www.js2coffee.org
```

I suggest you to use this as cross verification instead of correcting the code after getting compile error(Only during initial stages), I strongly recommend you to learn coffeescript instead of doing this conversion thing.

And If you want more detailed books on coffeescript apart from [Little Book](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/)
Try these,

[Programming in Coffee](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Programming_in_CoffeeScript.html?id=FaP-H_URQ2sC&redir_esc=y)
[Coffeescript Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript)